# Mag2 - Adding links to categories navigation bar and moving them

Tags: magento2

[image]

In Mag 2, I'm developing a template which extends Luma. How do I add a link after Sale and move all the links so they're in between the logo and the search box?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add top link you can follow below solution, 
**YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml**

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your.link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link-name</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Link-url</argument>
                    </arguments>
              </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks! I moved the element navigation.sections to header-wrapper so now they're beside the logo

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. You can up vote the answer if something you found useful. Thanks :)

Comment: Upvoted :) RIght now your solution gives me a list that is under the top links. Is there a way to append all links to one single row?

Comment: Currently I have not it tried. If I will know I would gladly inform you. JFYI you have not yet upvoted :) You can simply click on up arrow. Thanks in advance.